# How did Jesus steal the car keys?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-walking-dead

In S6E10 of The Walking Dead, Rick and Daryl go out on a supply run. They come across a [box truck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_truck) full of supplies in the back.

While using the truck to flip over a vending machine, a man comes from behind a building and surprises Rick and Daryl. Both of our heroes pull their guns on the man and interrogate him: he reveals himself as being named something unmemorable but having the nickname "Jesus."

Rick and Daryl disagree about how to handle this man, but end up telling him to hit the road.

Somehow, Jesus steals Rick's keys to the truck (but not the car they were previously driving), and drives off in it: Daryl asks Rick about the keys, and Rick grabs at his midsection and swears as though they were missing. I do not recall Jesus ever being within "grabbing" distance of Rick or Daryl, nor him being anywhere near either door of the box truck.

How did Jesus steal the keys to the box truck?

Notes:

1. Jesus appears to perform several other impossible stunts in the show, such as untying himself and catching up to a speeding vehicle, or breaking out of a makeshift prison cell and sneaking up on [Richonne](https://www.google.com/search?q=Richonne). While supporting evidence may leverage details from these other stunts, my question is not about these acts.
2. Given that this episode aired tonight, a spoiler warning *may* be desirable: however, the events in question occurred *very* early in the episode and reveal no plot surprises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Rick was ambushed.  [Jesus bumped into him](https://youtu.be/VSlu00-LWm4?t=1m1s) (a pretty easy "bump and run" which almost any pickpocket can easily do) and took the keys.  Jesus then created a diversion (the firecrackers), hopped in the truck and took off.

[image]

Comment: I do not recall Jesus bumping into Rick - not saying it did not happen, but this is the kind of detail I would look for after six years of TWD. Being that this episode aired mere hours ago and the discs are not available for a few months, do you have any evidence to back this up?

Comment: From the question: "I do not recall Jesus ever being within "grabbing" distance of Rick or Daryl" is there any evidence to the contrary? I am open to being wrong - I did view the episode but have no discs to review specific scenes - but would accept incontrovertible evidence that proves my preconceived notions incorrect. Also, the firecrackers would have been created before he encountered Rick and Daryl as he was in full view from the time he presented himself until they heard them.

Comment: I'll lay out the events for you, as i've just watched this scene back.'

1. Jesus probably spotted Rick and Daryl, lit the firecrackers (that had a few minutes fuse)

2. He then bumps into Rick, quite clearly. (this is when the keys were grabbed)

3. He then makes small talk long enough to get some distance to Rick and Daryl - knowing the firecrackers will distract them.

4. They go off, he gets in the van and makes his escape.

Comment: Also Snowman, you are aware the internet does exist, and these episodes of walking dead are available IMMEDIATELY after airing on any torrent website? ;)

Comment: @davidlumix yes, I am aware. I try to stay on the right side of the legal line, even if some people treat that line as more of a gray area ;-) If the answerer updates the answer with some evidence I will accept it.

Comment: Not sure where the "evidence" would come from, except maybe linking an illegally captured youtube clip.  ;o)

Comment: @Snowman - It happened.

Comment: @johnnybones - I got the gif, but I thought it would be unfair to use it in my own answer when yours was here first and was totally correct, so I edited it into your answer.  You can even see Jesus putting the keys in his pocket.

Comment: There's also a link to the video in the text.  Wasn't sure if you wanted it embedded in the answer.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Though, YouTube has its own copyright restrictions, so if it's on YouTube, then it's fair game and if it should *not* be on YouTube then that's their problem and not ours. But such small scenes usually seem to easily fall under "fair use" and this site already has millions of embedded videos of that kind. So there shouldn't be any legality problem with linking or embedding a YouTube video of the scene.

Comment: Thanks for the GIF video. I have Season 6 on preorder and may edit in HD still shots after it is released, but this is evidence enough to accept the answer right now.

Comment: You are too kind, @R.J.MacReady.  Shoulda saved it for someone who needed it more than me.  :o)